# Is Grunt or Sprockets better to cope with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is Grunt or Sprockets better to cope with rails? Rails uses sprockets by default to  manage assets in application.I'm thinking to integrate Grunt into the rails application instead of sprockets.Am i choosing the correct a better way or making it worse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [webpacker](https://clarkdave.net/2015/01/how-to-use-webpack-with-rails/) instead of grunt, New Rails 6 is integrated with webpacker for asset compiling